# Difference between wait() and this.wait()

Tags: java, wait, synchronized

I got a java code snippet here which got me wondering what the difference between the calls `wait()` and `this.wait()` is.

Lets say you have a class with a method to take a resource and that is synchronized. Normally I would write `wait()` in the `while` loop if the resource is not available but what happens if you call `this.wait()`? Whose monitor will be blocked? The monitor of the class object or the resource? And to which object does the statement `"this"` refer to?

Sorry for asking this super basic question but I couldn't find any help through google.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: For a method there is no difference.  For variables, `someVar` might be a parameter, and hence different from `this.someVar`.

Comment: This isn't specific to the `wait` method. All instance method calls (not called on an object variable) have an implicit `this.` on the front. Often I will type `this.` just to get a list of available methods for the current object

Comment: They are the same, but, for instance say you had an inner `Thread` inside of your current thread. In order to make sure you call the correct `wait()` method, you need to prefix `this.wait` with the class name you are referring to. E.g. `MyParentThread.this.wait()` would call the parent thread's wait() method if you are in the run method of the child thread. calling `this.wait()` inside of the child thread would call the child threads `wait()` method. This isn't pertinent to your question I know, but I feel it needed to be addressed for any onlookers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't any difference in that case, `this.wait()` and `wait()` will call the same method.

Take a look at the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) about the `this` keyword in Java.

From the documentation:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, ***this*** is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using ***this***.

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 haha every time I reload the page you have given more helpful information

Answer (score 1):

`this` Keyword refers to the current instance of the class, and since calling `wait()` from the object itself already refers to the current instance's function, there is no difference between `wait()` and `this.wait()` in your case.